# Como acessar uma versão anterior e depois voltar para a mais recente git checkout

Tags: git, commit, checkout

A dúvida é simples: Imagine que eu tenha 10 versões. Utilizei o `git checkout` na sexta para analisar rapidamente uma linha.

Como posso retornar para a versão mais recente se o ID dela sumiu do meu `git log`? Como posso utilizar o `git checkout` para a mais atual sem saber o ID dela já que a sexta é meu "atual `HEAD`".

Muito obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Não ficou claro para mim o que aconteceu. "git checkout master" não resolve o seu problema?

Comment: Não sabia da existência desse comando. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @MarcosBanik, como encontrou a resposta para a pergunta do AP, que tal fornecer uma resposta para a pergunta? :)

Answer (score 1):

Se você foi para um commit específico e deseja retornar para o commit mais recente da branch, basta fazer novamente o checkout da própria branch:

```
git checkout 123456 # hash de um commit específico
git checkout nome_branch # vai para o commit mais recente da branch
```

Se quiser retornar ao checkout **anterior** (e não para o commit mais recente), você pode usar:

```
git checkout -
```

Que funciona de maneira similar ao `cd -` no Linux, voltando para o diretório que você estava anteriormente.